# Get MySql DB table column value by searching of another column value of particular record with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, typescript, ionic2

.Hello,

I'm new with Type Script and PHP

I'm trying to figure out

For example if this way I can check if value of inputed name exist in database table column:

```
    <?php
    require 'connection.php';

    $name = $_POST['name'];

    $sql = "SELECT * from nameTab where name='$name'";

    if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)==1)
    {
        echo 'Name exist';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Name does not exist';
    }
    ?>
```

how to get, for example **username** with searching by inputed string of **name** or **ID** value from particular record another column in MySQL database table with **ID**, **name** and **username** columns?

For example, to be more clear, if my database content:

```
ID | name   |   username
------------------------
1  | Sally  |   sally123
2  | Jack   |   jack120
3  | Leila  |   leila77
4  | Roy    |   roy800 
5  | Sara   |   sara444
```

if I search for **Leila** in *name* column, I want to get value of *username* column **leila77** or ID **3**

I do not think it matters, but I want to use this connection in Ionic2 project Type Script code

**Edit by answer:**

TS:

```
check() {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let postParams = '&name=' + this.name;

    this.http.post("http://site.info/php/check.php", JSON.stringify(postParams), options)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data['_body']);
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

check.php:

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';

$name = $_POST['name'];

$sql = "SELECT * from nameTab where name='$name'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
   echo $row["username"];
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: you want enter either name or id and code will identify it to search the user name right ?

Comment: @Shahroz Shaikh Hello, yes exactly, I guess would be perfect get chosen or all other columns of particular record with insertion of one of them, for example ID and name by insertion of username, or name and username by insertion of ID, or just name by insertion of username, as it is described in my question. So the basic idea is to get value or values of other columns  from particular record with searching  of value by any column

Answer (score 0):

Using that SQL query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from nameTab where name='$name'";
```

Evaluate the statement

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Then iterate over the result

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "username: " . $row["username"] . "with id: " . $row["id"] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Hello, I've added edit to my question by your answer, but console appears without echo of given values, not sure what is wrong there

Comment: This seems to be an problem on the frontend then, not on the backend. Can you show the exact output of the php server?

Comment: Sure I've added TypeScript to edit by your answer, not sure how to get this echo value

Comment: In your TS, postParams is not a JS Object, but rather a simple string with the form "&name=abc", you can't encode that as a JSON string. I assume that because of that, your POST request does not send the parameter with it, the server does not find any results because it will never have a name to search for, and therefore it will always not send a response.

Answer (score 0):

try to identify if name is null or id is null

```
$sql ="select username,"
```

either of them is null add it in the query

```
$sql = $sql+ "'$name'"
```

then add where with condition

```
$sql= $sql +'where id = '$id'"
```

i didn't remember the php code for it but this logic will be use for these conditions